# android studio error startup in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

I had installed android studio in ubuntu 13.04 , it'was so easy but when I launch it a first error was printed in terminal:

```
ERROR: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1269)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1244)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1349)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeAndWaitIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:1991)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProject(ExternalSystemUtil.java:353)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProjects(ExternalSystemUtil.java:228)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemStartupActivity$1.run(ExternalSystemStartupActivity.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemStartupActivity.runActivity(ExternalSystemStartupActivity.java:50)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$2.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:149)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivities(StartupManagerImpl.java:264)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.access$100(StartupManagerImpl.java:55)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$3.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:167)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.runWhenSmart(DumbServiceImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runPostStartupActivitiesFromExtensions(StartupManagerImpl.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl$4.run(ProjectManagerImpl.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$5.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:291)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:493)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:304)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:185)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:226)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:175)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:695)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:154)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:356)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:241)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:700)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:525)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:348)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:765)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:195)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:715)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:300)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:294)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:254)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.openProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:414)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.loadAndOpenProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:501)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtil.openProject(ProjectUtil.java:179)
    at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManager.doOpenProject(RecentProjectsManager.java:46)
    at com.intellij.ide.RecentProjectsManagerBase$MyAppLifecycleListener.appStarting(RecentProjectsManagerBase.java:321)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:228)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:219)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:209)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$000(MessageBusImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$1.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.appStarting(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.loadProject(IdeaApplication.java:296)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.access$500(IdeaApplication.java:56)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter$2.run(IdeaApplication.java:263)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:343)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:700)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:525)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:348)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
[  35681]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - null 
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.java:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:69)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeAndWaitIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:1994)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProject(ExternalSystemUtil.java:353)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProjects(ExternalSystemUtil.java:228)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemStartupActivity$1.run(ExternalSystemStartupActivity.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemStartupActivity.runActivity(ExternalSystemStartupActivity.java:50)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$2.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:149)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivities(StartupManagerImpl.java:264)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.access$100(StartupManagerImpl.java:55)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$3.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:167)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.runWhenSmart(DumbServiceImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runPostStartupActivitiesFromExtensions(StartupManagerImpl.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl$4.run(ProjectManagerImpl.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$5.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:291)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:493)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:304)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:185)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:226)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:175)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:695)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:154)
[  35688]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Android Studio (I/O Preview) AI-130.677228  Build #AI-130.677228 
[  35688]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - JDK: 1.7.0_21 
[  35688]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[  35688]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[  35688]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - OS: Linux 
[  35688]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Last Action:  
[  38020]   WARN - openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl - ToolWindow icons should be 13x13. Please fix icon path=/icons/androidPreview.png class=class icons.AndroidIcons
```

and a second one was after starting Android studio in Event view :

```
AssertionError: null: null
```

so can you help me to tell me what's wrong in all that .

Thanks .

Comment: Try setting up the JAVA_HOME and JRE path, and then try..

Comment: I tried your advice by setting : "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0" but it's a same problem !

Comment: Name one Path as ANDROID_STUDIO and other as JAVA_HOME, using the same path and let me know, if it is working for you.

Comment: thanks for your fast feedback but no there is not a change

Comment: I think that was all right your advice http://stackoverflow.com/users/1321290/anupamam .... it was a mistake in command ubuntu just a sudo -i make a difference !

Answer (score 0):

I used wmname to change the name of the window manager.

Awesome seems to cause this bug. Just do something like:

```
$ wmname LG3D
$ android-studio
```

source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82362